# python time plotting, not working with data with microseconds

Tags: python, matplotlib, astropy

I have a dataset with 589 datetime strings and 589 points. The time seq has msec accuracy. e.g. -

```
['2022-10-07 12:05:39.866', '2022-10-07 12:05:40.914',
       '2022-10-07 12:05:41.963', '2022-10-07 12:05:43.012',
       '2022-10-07 12:05:44.060', '2022-10-07 12:05:45.109',
       '2022-10-07 12:05:46.157', '2022-10-07 12:05:47.206',
       '2022-10-07 12:05:48.254', '2022-10-07 12:05:49.303']
```

I'm using astropy Time, so I convert this list using

`dateTimeTags = Time(dateTimeTags, format='iso', scale='utc')` to get something like this:

```
<Time object: scale='utc' format='iso' value=['2022-10-07 12:05:39.866' '2022-10-07 12:05:40.914']>
```

but that goes from `2022-10-07 12:05:39.866` to `2022-10-07 12:15:56.429`. About 10 min.

The data is just floats...

When I do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matdates.SecondLocator(interval=10))

ax.plot_date(dateTimeTags, data,'-') 
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

I get

```
 ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: <Time object: scale='utc' format='iso' ...
```

When I try

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))

ax.plot(dateTimeTags, data,'-')
```

I get

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Any idea how I plot this? The [astropy site](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/visualization/matplotlib_integration.html#plotting-times) says I should have no problem.

Comment: Did you call `astropy.visualization.time_support`, like the docs say?

Comment: I did not..  let me go back to the docs. I guess I missed that.